# Strange behavior ALT+moving lines in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: text-editors, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, computer-behavior

Development was going well today, when all of a sudden something horrible happened to my editor within my Visual Studio 2015. I do this thing where I move/alternate the lines of code up or down by pressing **ALT** + **UP** or **DOWN**. It usually works just fine, however I slipped and bumped a few keys on my keyboard today and now here is what happens...

Whenever I do the line moving/alternating thing, the entire text-editor scrolls *with* it... I thought for a second that this was just *scroll-lock*... So I tried to toggle that key a few times and the problem did not go away. So now I tried rebooting my computer, thinking it might go away but nope... still there. I think there is some weird going on with a setting in Visual Studio, can somebody please explain what on earth is going on?

EDIT 1:

It's even a little worse than I described, here is a more detailed description of what is happening. No matter whether I ALT/move the lines UP or DOWN the scroll bar just moves down-ward with every ALT/move command, until resetting itself and returning back to the top.

EDIT 2:

Figured something else out. This only really happens when I move a method signature UP or DOWN, but not with the rest of the text in the editor. I tried this on someone else's computer, but I cannot recreate it. I am still convinced that this is some sort of configuration issue or maybe even a bug with VS.

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: Yes, that didn't work. I also have more detail, which I will add to the question. Thanks.